# Which is faster in C# XML or SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Which is faster in C#:to read tiny XML files or to read tiny SQL tables with small amount of data ?

I wonder if is really necessary to create a table in SQL then establish a connection just to read 10 or 11 parameters.

What would you reccomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on what You need. Nothing stops You from even combining the two worlds as XML can easily be stored in SQL Server.

If You want to actually have the authentication of the SQL Server, have it backed up, versioned or whatever, You can easily design a mixed XML, SQL, table solution. If You really need some propertyBag persistence area files are ok, but they still require care ie. access control, taking care when it is not present etc (reading a file still does throw a lot of exceptions and IT does it with some good reason).

Ask Yourself questions like: do I need restricted access, how will I report changes (if any),

- do I need version history,
- do I read all the parameters or only part of
  it?
- what Do i need to do if someone
  changes an entry?
- what should I do when there is no entry?
- does it need to be extensible (new parameters added/removed)?
- should it be encrypted?
- does the database layer needs to know about it?

Just some thought from the top of my head.
Luke

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a handful of 'settings' that you want to read, I would definitely go with a small XML file.  I can't say definitively that it would be faster, but given that you would eliminate the over head of establishing the connection, authenticating, etc it would definitely be simpler.

And if you can use LINQ to XML, its really easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Speed is not the only consideration.  You don't have as much admin overhead with XML files as you would with SQL Server.

If the file is local, it will certainly be faster to read using direct file than networked SQL access.  Far less between you and the data.  No impact on your process from other SQL usage.

Answer (score 1):

reading a lot of files is slow so if you have tons of xml files i would vote for SQL especially if we consider the fact that you have to parse the xml files as well which is way more complicated and more time consuming then making a connection to a DB especially if the DB is on the localhost :)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL based method: pros**
Easy to migrate, configure
**SQL based method: cons**
Connection can be down, connection takes time to establish, DB admin will wonder why there is a tiny table that has no meaning, codebase become unnecessarily complex
**File based method: pros**
Fast, no overhead on DB
**File based method:cons**
Migration is an issue. Configuration is an issue. Can easily get corrupted.